# How to loop on classes inheriting from std::vector contained in boost :: any

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have a base class who inherit from `std::vector`:

```
template<typename T>
class Base : public std::vector<T>
{
  std::vector<T> vect_;
public:
  Base() : std::vector<T>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}){}

  const std::vector<T>  getContainer() const { return vect_;}
};
```

and I have stored multiple-objects in a container of `boost::any`

When I go through I want to loop over the elements who inherit from `std::vector`.

I have done the following thing (which works)

```
  Base<int>     a;
  boost::any c = static_cast<decltype(a.getContainer())>(a);
  try
  {
    for (auto elem : boost::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(c))
      std::cout << elem << std::endl;
  }
  catch (boost::bad_any_cast)
  {}
```

I was wondering if there is an other way to do this kind of thing, because it's seems that you can't `boost::any_cast` into a parent class.

Comment: Erm... so... you inherit publicly from `std::vector`, and then add a function to retrieve a copy of that vector? Why can't you just use `std::vector` directly?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes actually I was looking for a generic way to loop over element with the for loop in C++11, so container of the stl or personal container.

Comment: `const std::vector<T>  getContainer() const { return vect_;}` looks terribly wrong

Comment: You shouldn't inherit from STL containers.

Comment: It looks like the design is tangled up. `Base` is derived from `vector<T>` and it has a data member of type `vector<T>`. That seems unlikely...

Comment: @PeteBecker It's was just a test to try to loop over the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this hypothetical container supports `begin`/`end`:

```
template<typename TContainer>
void do_foo(TContainer const& c) {
    for (auto const& i : c)
        foo(i); 
}
```

Casting anything like you're doing is a terrible misunderstanding of how generic programming works.

If you want have a container of such different containers, using new `Boost.TypeErasure` `any` might help you. I figure you will need predicates such as

```
BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((has_begin), begin, 0)
BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((has_end), end, 0)
```

However, this approach is (at best) incomplete. Per suggestions from @R.Martinho Fernandes, this type won't allow you to take everything that can be used in range `for`. All `std` containers can use `std::begin` and `std::end`, which are found via ADL, and these functions could be found for your containers too. You'd need something like that to be really covered here.

And that makes another point: *Why?*

Comment: Actually I'm just trying to find a base class from which stl container and personal container can inherit in order to loop over it.
I'm looking at boost typeErasure

Comment: Thanks for BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER I will take a look at it but I think with all the comments it's going to be hard.
For the why, I'm trying to parse a django-template file and reproduce a part of the output and I'm actually on the loops